# android : bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android

I am using android Camera. Also using auto focusing feature. After capturing image more then 10 times getting the following exception:
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

my source code is following:

```
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                try {
                    // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new
                    // ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                    Utility.gc();
                    Bitmap bmp = decodeFile(data);
                    Utility.gc();
                    // BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                    // data.length, o);
                    // Bitmap bmpCompressed = rotateBitmap(bmp, 90, 320, 430);

                    Bitmap bmpCompressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 430, 320,
                            true);
                    bmp.recycle();
                    Utility.gc();
                    writeBmp(bmpCompressed);
                    bmpCompressed.recycle();
                    Utility.gc();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);

                } finally {
                    isImageCapture = true;
                }

            }

        };
private Bitmap decodeFile(byte[] buffer) {

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer),
                null, o2);

    }
```

how can i get rid from the above mention exception?

Answer (score 3):

Use

> **Options.inSampleSize**

```
// Decode image size
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inSampleSize = 8; 
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer), null, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do the scaling yourself using `BitmapFactory.Options` and [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options;
options.inSampleSize = 4; // might try 8 also
BitmapFactory.decoderByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
```

There are also other options in [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) to play around with.

You are probably running out of memory because you create a full decoded bitmap before you do the scaling.

Comment: You may need to increase the sample size or decrease the dimensions of your image. Also, make sure that this it the only code you're using for decoding. In other words, you shouldn't be creating intermediate bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this bug report:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488

There's a known bug in Android relating to this error message, which doesn't seem to be accepted by Google. There are workarounds in the bug report if this is the problem you're having. I've used them to clear up similar issues.

Comment: Adrian i think you are right. Because i have facing same problem. do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use less memory.

It definitely sounds like you have a memory leak somewhere if it works until the 10th picture is taken. Use the DDMS tools in Eclipse to track memory to try to see where it's happening.